# Controlling Classification Cut-off in glm() in R

Tags: r, glm

Issue related to R -

I have a CSV dataset obtained as:

```
mydata <- read.csv("data.csv", header = TRUE)
```

which contains the variable 'y' (y is binary 0 or 1) and also another variable 'weight' (weight is a numerical variable - taking fractional values between 0 and 1).

I split up mydata into train (80%) and test(20%) as:

```
d<-sort(sample(nrow(mydata), nrow(mydata)*0.8));
train <- mydata[d,];
test < -mydata[-d,];
```

Then, I perform weighted glm (essentially, logistic regression) on train as:

```
#Build GLM model on train data ***(A)
model <-glm(y~., data = train, weights = train$weight, family = binomial);

#Apply model on test ***(B)
score <-predict(model, type = 'response',test);

#Get classification for each observation in test as 'positive' or 'negative' ***(C)
classify <-performance(score,"tpr","fpr");
```

My question here is:
 In step (B) & (C), how do I control the classification rule, i.e. R might classify observations with model-fitted probability > 0.5 as a 'positive' and <= 0.5 as a 'negative'. Is there a way I can change this threshold to say, 0.75 instead of whatever R might be using (I used 0.5 as example).

Comment: where does the `performance` function come from? AFAIK it's not part of base R.  `predict(...,type="response")` returns probabilities (values between 0 and 1), not 0/1 or success/failure: control of what counts as positive vs. negative will be controllable in `performance()`, if at all.  (I *think* the [ROCR package](http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/R/library/ROCR/html/performance.html) ?)

Answer (score 0):

You could write a function that would round up or down the probabilities you get from `predict`.

For example:

```
threshold_ceil <- function(num, thresh=0.25){
  if (num < thresh) {
    ret <- floor(num)
  }
  else {
    ret <- ceiling(num)
  }
  return (ret)
}
```

Then you could apply it to your probabilities:

```
score <-predict(model, type='response', test)
probs_25 <- sapply(score, threshold_ceil)
probs_20 <- sapply(score, threshold_ceil, 0.2)
```

Then compare your confusion matrices:

```
table(probs_25, y)  
table(probs_20, y)
```